# Tricky shift values from specific rows to another row using Pandas with multi-index columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am looking to shift values from specific rows to another row using Pandas.

**Data**

```
        cn_positions    cn_positions    cn_positions
Date    Q1.22           Q1.23           Q1.24   
ID              
AA      73              87              104 
BB      0               0               13  
CC      0               20              62  
CC      0               0               11
```

**Desired**

```
        cn_positions_Q1.22  cn_positions_Q1.23  cn_positions_Q1.24
Date                
ID              
AA      73                  87                  104 
BB      0                   0                   13  
CC      0                   20                  62  
CC      0                   0                   11
```

**Doing**

```
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df.unstack().reset_index(), values=0, index='ID', columns='Date').rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

However, the above seems to eliminate the Q1.22,Q1.23 values. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: should Date and ID be empty after the move? it looks like you're updating the column names

Comment: hi @ti7 the values in the Date row should be shifted upward and attached to the values in the very top row.

Comment: the desired and initial look the same just with different column names?

Comment: is date an actual row? or is it a multi index column header?

Comment: hi, @JoranBeasley no they are far from the same.
In the desired, we are attaching _Q1.22  ,   _Q1.23  ,  _Q1.24    to  cn_positions in the top row

Comment: yes you are correct @JoranBeasley it is a multi index column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first it looks to me like the daterow is just part of a multi index column name

not an actual row

if that is the case
`df.columns = [f"{x}_{y}" for x,y in df.columns]` should flatten it

for example

```
df.columns = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("cn_positions","Q1.22"),("cn_positions","Q1.23"),("cn_positions","Q1.24")])
df
Out[7]: 
  cn_positions            
         Q1.22 Q1.23 Q1.24
0            1     2     3
1            4     5     6
2            7     8     9
df.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a,b in df.columns]
df
Out[9]: 
   cn_positions_Q1.22  cn_positions_Q1.23  cn_positions_Q1.24
0                   1                   2                   3
1                   4                   5                   6
2                   7                   8                   9
```